# Extract exactly four integers from string in regex

Tags: python, regex

```
list1 = ['Contact: Hamdan Z Hamdan, MBBS, Msc',
        '\r\n            ',
        '+249912468264',
        '\r\n                  ',
        'hamdanology@hotmail.com',
        '\r\n                ',
        'Contact: Maha I Mohammed, MBBS, PhD',
        '\r\n            ',
        '+249912230895',
        '\r\n                  ',
        '\r\n                ',
        'Sudan',
        'Jaber abo aliz',
        '\r\n                  ',
        'Recruiting',
        '\r\n          ',
        'Khartoum, Sudan, 1111  ',
        u'Contact: Khaled H Bakheet, MD,PhD \xa0 \xa0 +249912957764 \xa0 \xa0 ',
        'khalid2_3456@yahoo.com',
        u' \xa0 \xa0 ',
        u'Principal Investigator: Hamdan Z Hamdan, MBBS,MSc \xa0 \xa0  \xa0 \xa0  \xa0 \xa0 ',
       'Principal Investigator:',
       '\r\n      ',
       'Hamdan Z Hamdan, MBBS, MSc',
       '\r\n            ',
        'Al-Neelain University',
        '\r\n                '
    ]
```

From this list of strings I need to extract only 4 digit integers which should not be associated with other characters?

Example: '1111' only is the needed output.

How we should write the regex in python? Obviously, this won't work: `*([\d]{4})*`.

Comment: If something doesn't work, it's helpful to indicate *what happened instead of what you expected*.

Comment: What do you mean by "should not be associated with"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to select the integers which has length 4 only.it is the solitude string from the text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\b` in a regular expression to indicate a word boundary, so the following will work for you:

```
import re

for s in list1:
    m = re.search(r'\b\d{4}\b', s)
    if m:
        print m.group(0)
```

... which just outputs `1111`.  The [documentation for `\b`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) explains further:

> `\b`
>
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. [...]

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following

```
>>> [l for l in (re.findall(r"[^\d](\d{4})[^\d]",s) for s in list1) if l]
[['1111'], ['3456']]
```

In case you are only interested in four digit numbers on word boundary use

```
>>> [l for l in (re.findall(r"\b\d{4}\b",s) for s in list1) if l]
[['1111']]
```

Comment: The parentheses in the word boundary version are redundant.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Agreed. Forgot to remove them when re-wrote the second expression from first